# assignment operator in actual parameter list

Tags: c++, parameter-passing

```
int main ()
{
char* a[5] = {0}
char* b = //char type address here.;
char c[] = "copy";
strcpy(a[1] = b, c);
}
```

How does `strcpy(a[1] = b`get evaluated? Does `a[1]`get sent to the function?

*I can't test this atm, i'm on my phone.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `a[1] = b` is evaluated, then the *result* is passed as an argument. The result is neither `a[1]` not `b`, but it's equal to both.

You can think of it like this instead

```
char *compiler_generated_temp_variable = a[1] = b;
strcpy(compiler_generated_temp_variable, c);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the C++ Standard

> 5.17 Assignment and compound assignment operators
>
> 1 The assignment operator (=) and the compound assignment operators
>   all group right-to-left. All require a modifiable lvalue as their left
>   operand and **return an lvalue referring to the left operand**.

Thus this statement

```
strcpy(a[1] = b, c);
```

is equivalent to statement with the comma operator

```
a[1] = b, strcpy( a[1], c);
```

So the answer to your question

> Does a[1]get sent to the function?

will be that you are right (my congratulation:)). a[1] get sent to the function after the assignment b to it.